# Launching Visual Studio 2013 whilst connected to AX2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, reporting, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I feel a little guilty posting this question on here but I'm stuck. I know I need to lauch the exe with a /AxConfig switch, whilst pointing to an AX instance. However I am presented with an error - unknown switch.

Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : AxConfig.

The exe target is

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /AxConfig "---ax config folder path to the axc---"

I'm prepared to slap my self in the face as I get the feeling the answer is annoying obvious. ek!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't 100% clear to me but I have a guess.  This is the relevant MSDN link for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889291.aspx

So it's one of 2 things. It sounds like the second one.

1. You aren't typing the command correctly, it should be something like this:

> `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
>   /AxConfig z:\Config\ContosoDev.axc`

2. You don't have Visual Studio Tools installed, so `/AxConfig` isn't recognized.  When you install AX 2012, you choose what components you want to install.  See the below screenshot I just took. Note, depending on what version of AX 2012, your screenshot may be slightly different but what to install is the same.

[image]

**EDIT:** Also, depending on what revision of AX (R2, R3, etc) different versions of Visual Studio are supported. Only 2010 or only 2013. They add support for different versions as the time passes, so you'll have to search your version of AX to see what's supported.

Comment: Thanks Alex - I'll check this now.

Comment: Attempted this but I don't have "Visual Studio 2013 Tools" as an option.

Comment: It could be a different revision of AX (AX 2012 R2, R3, etc) do you have the one above it called `Visual Studio Tools`? And depending on what version of AX you have, Visual Studio 2010 might be the only one supported. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2014/11/24/visual-studio-tools-for-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-r3-cu8-now-requires-microsoft-visual-studio-2013/ and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309576.aspx . It's easier to find your version of AX and see what version is supported.